# Does the case of a stereotype matter?

Tags: uml, stereotype

UML 2.5 uses lots of standard stereotypes and they are all typeset somehow (camel case seems to be default). But: it the casing relevant? There are only two occurrences of *uppercase* and *lowercase* in the whole document. Neither refers to stereotype (or keyword) usage.

Comment: Interesting question. I just noticed that all the keywords are lower-case (see annex C),  and all the stereotypes are upper-cased (see chapter 22). There is one exception:  the «Stereotype» keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it in the specs for UML 2.5 at page 260:

> Normally a Stereotype’s name starts with an upper-case letter, to
> follow the convention for naming Classes. However Profiles may use
> different conventions. Matching between the names of Stereotype
> definitions and applications is **case-insensitive**, so naming stereotype
> applications with lower-case letters where the stereotypes are defined
> using upper-case letters is valid,
> although stylistically obsolete. For legacy reasons a tool may display
> stereotype names with the initial letter in lower case even when
> defined in upper case.

Stereotypes are **case-insensitive**

Comment: I also scanned for _case_  but obviously there are tons of _usecase_ and similar texts... Thanks!

Comment: Not a year and I already forgot your answer here :-/